# T-SQL converting VARCHAR to date

Tags: date, t-sql, type-conversion, format

A customer gave me a database with all the fields in VARCHAR(150).
I have a date field in the format dd/mm/yy that I am willing to convert in type DATE.
I have found that you can manage to change the type of the date with the function CONVERT like this:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 3)
```

which gives:

```
30/12/06
```

But it only works if the field is recognized as a DATE.

My request gives is :

```
SELECT TOP(1000) CAST("Date" AS date) FROM "1_MVENTE"
```

And I have this error message :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

It fails when the day is getting above 12 because T-SQL is expectid an American date format.
For example 12/12/2021 works but not 13/12/2021.

I don't know how to explain to T-SQL that my input field is a VARCHAR but has to be read as a date dd/mm/yy to be transformed.

Comment: use `CONVERT()` with style `3` in your second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONVERT` a style code. Also switch to `TRY_CONVERT` which will return `NULL` when the value cannot be converted, as it is *very* likely you have poor data quality and so invalid dates (like `'29/02/21'`, `'03/17/22'` or `'33/12/20'`). Style `3` is `dd/MM/yy`

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date,[date],3)
FROM dbo.[1_MVENTE];
```

Of course, what you really should be doing is fixing your design. A column called `date` that is actually storing a `varchar` is by definition *not* a `date`. `varchar` is not a "one size fits all" data type; use the correct data type for your data.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working :). You are absolutly right for the design but the database is not mine, it belongs to a customer; That' why i'm trying to change the datatypes